# ValueError: Cannot assign must be an instance

Tags: django

I have the following pre-existing database table which contains and id and a description.  I have to load this prior to my User table in order to associate the ForeignKey correctly.

```
class QVDSSSecurityDimension(models.Model):

    coid = models.CharField(db_column='CM_Data_Restriction', serialize=False, max_length=10, primary_key = True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid_name = models.CharField(db_column='CM_Company_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_DSS_Security_Dimension'
```

My custom user model is built on the following:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    officename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positioncode = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.ForeignKey(QVDSSSecurityDimension, null=True, blank = True, db_constraint=False)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

#    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s %s' % (self.username, self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Everything works with the makemigrations and migrate, but if a User.coid doesn't exist in the database I get the following error while attempting to login:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'08732'": "User.coid" must be a "QVDSSSecurityDimension" instance.
```

I verified that coid does exists in the QVDSSSecurityDimension, but since there are no Users in the table with the coid it's throwing that error.  How can I make my login still function properly if a user verifies with AD and their coid doesn't exist in the custom user table yet?

I've tried Null = True and Blank = True with db_constraint = True and nothing seems to work.  The coid will exist after the user is stored to the database, but this error happens prior to that occurring.

Here is my profile view

```
def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername, active = 1).values('report_name_sc')

    reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_id', flat=True)
    reportaccess = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= reportIds).values_list('report_name_sc', flat = True).distinct()
    reportGroups = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_group_id', flat=True)
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).exclude(active=0)

    allreports = 'All Reports'

    if allreports in reportaccess:
        bhreportgrouplist = None
        cereportgrouplist = None
        finreportgrouplist = None
        careportgrouplist = None
        pireportgrouplist = None
        screportgrouplist = None
        dssreportgrouplist = None
        psgreportgrouplist = None
        othreportgrouplist = None
        showbutton = None
    else:
        bhreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 200)
        cereportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 500)
        finreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 600)
        careportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 800)
        pireportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1100)
        screportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1200)
        dssreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1300)
        psgreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1400)
        othreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 99999)
        showbutton = ""



    args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportaccess, 'applicationlist':reportlist, 'bhgrouplist':bhreportgrouplist, 'cegrouplist':cereportgrouplist, 'fingrouplist':finreportgrouplist
          , 'cagrouplist':careportgrouplist, 'pigrouplist':pireportgrouplist, 'scgrouplist':screportgrouplist, 'dssgrouplist':dssreportgrouplist, 'psggrouplist':psgreportgrouplist
          , 'othgrouplist':othreportgrouplist, 'showbutton':showbutton}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

I'm able to get the coid from my formattedusername without the DSSSecurityDimension because it pulls it from AD, however i need the description from DSSSecurityDimension, which is why I pull in the coid on the profile template, but from User.coid not DSSSecurityDimension.coid.

Coid in my template is rendered with the following li

```
<li>Coid: {{ user.coid }}</li>
```

The line of code is in the python libraries and not my view, which tells me its an issue with my model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 54, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 150, in login
    )(request)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_w
rapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 90, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 182, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 385, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 412, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 187, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 70, in authenticate
    user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 115, in _authenticate_with_backend
    return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django_python3_ldap\auth.py", line 23, in authenticate
    return ldap.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django_python3_ldap\ldap.py", line 205, in authenticate
    return c.get_user(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django_python3_ldap\ldap.py", line 115, in get_user
    return self._get_or_create_user(self._connection.response[0])
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django_python3_ldap\ldap.py", line 67, in _get_or_create_user
    **user_lookup
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 482, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 498, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 68, in __init__
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 554, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 216, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'08732'": "User.coid" must be a "QVDSSSecurityDimension" instance.
```

The login is handled in my settings.py

with the following:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"

# The URL of the LDAP server.
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://ip of server"


# Initiate TLS on connection.
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = False

# The LDAP search base for looking up users.
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "DC=domainname,DC=corpad,DC=net"

LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "user"

# User model fields mapped to the LDAP
# attributes that represent them.
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
    "coid": "extensionAttribute10",
    "facility": "company",
    "officename":"physicalDeliveryOfficeName",
   "streetaddress": "streetAddress",
    "jobdescription":"corpadNet2001-CORPds-JobCodeDescription",
    "positioncode":"corpadNet2001-CORPds-PositionCode",
    "positiondescription":"corpadNet2001-CORPds-PositionCodeDescription",
    "title":"title",
}

# A tuple of django model fields used to uniquely identify a user.
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

# Path to a callable that takes a dict of {model_field_name: value},
# returning a dict of clean model data.
# Use this to customize how data loaded from LDAP is saved to the User model.
LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

# Path to a callable that takes a user model and a dict of {ldap_field_name: [value]},
# and saves any additional user relationships based on the LDAP data.
# Use this to customize how data loaded from LDAP is saved to User model relations.
# For customizing non-related User model fields, use LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA.
LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

# Path to a callable that takes a dict of {ldap_field_name: value},
# returning a list of [ldap_search_filter]. The search filters will then be AND'd
# together when creating the final search filter.
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"

# Path to a callable that takes a dict of {model_field_name: value}, and returns
# a string of the username to bind to the LDAP server.
# Use this to support different types of LDAP server.
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
```

Comment: Can you post the views your'e using to login ?

Comment: I added more detail with the views, but i believe the issue is in the way the data is modeled since i'm using the ldap3 authentication.  My login is the users network login and password, once the user is validated the database will write the record to my user table, which is the save in the User model.  However, it doesn't even get to that point because the relationship for my foreignkey doesn't have the coid in database.  If i manually add a dummy user with the coid of the test user, it works fine because the coid already exists in my user table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I see the problem. You expect `User`'s `coid` field to contain the actual ID of the related `QVDSSSecurityDimension` object, but this is not how `ForeignKey` works by default.

The `User`'s `coid` field is actually an attribute that exists only inside your Python logic. At database level, there's no `coid` column in the `User` table. This is because Django creates another field that is not explicitly declared in your model, called `coid_id`, to hold the related object's ID. *That* is the column and value that actually exists in the database.

In other words, if you list the attributes of a `User` object, you'll see it has two fields: `coid` and `coid_id`. `coid` will retrieve an instance of `QVDSSSecurityDimension`, while `coid_id` will hold the actual value you're trying to set.

Check [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) regarding this. [This post](http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/22/getting-the-id-of-related-objects-in-django/) can also help you understand how `coid` and `coid_id` work.

This is what I think you're looking for:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    co = models.ForeignKey(QVDSSSecurityDimension, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I renamed `coid` to `co` to make it more intuitive, since it doesn't hold the actual ID. I also removed `db_constraint=False`, since the default `db_constraint=True` should work just fine.

And when you try to set the `QVDSSSecurityDimension` to your user, you can either do:

```
some_user = User.objects.first()
some_dimension = QVDSSSecurityDimension.objects.get(coid='08732')

some_user.co = some_dimension
some_user.save()
```

or:

```
some_user = User.objects.first()
some_dimension = QVDSSSecurityDimension.objects.get(coid='08732')

some_user.co_id = some_dimension.coid
some_user.save()
```

or:

```
some_user = User.objects.first()
some_dimension_id = '08732'

some_user.co_id = some_dimension_id
some_user.save()
```

See the difference? I hope this helps clear things up a bit. :)

**EDIT**

Specifically, the problem was in the settings variable `LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS`, that was trying to map the ID inside `extensionAttribute10` (data received from `LDAP`) to the `User`'s `coid` field, which expected a `QVDSSSecurityDimension` instance. The solution was to change that key in the `LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS` from `coid` to `coid_id`.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, but I think you may have misunderstood.  My User model is created from active directory, using LDAP authentication.  All users do have a coid.  Once a users validates with their network login, their user information from AD is written to the database table user.  My current logic will work if there is an existing user in the database with the same coid, but if not it throws the error above.  I am just trying to use the QVDSSSecurityDimension to create a relationship on the coid so I can pull the name.

Comment: Huh, I see. But judging by the error it's pretty clear that at some point your code is trying to assign a string to a field that expects a `QVDSSSecurityDimension` instance. Can you edit your question including the code you use to login? Or at least the code in the specific line that throws the error according to the traceback.

Comment: For the login there is no custom code it's all part of the ldap3 library and once it's configured it works.  We aren't using the coid from DSS Security after the login, only on the submit but the application won't let me get that far if the coid doesn't already exist in user, which it won't when the app is first deployed.  I've added my views for the profile, which occurs after the login.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! OK my theory is that the problem is inside the [_get_or_create_user](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap/blob/dc7873cfb75335f5f8b41338413123ea53aa4d4a/django_python3_ldap/ldap.py#L32) in the `django-python3-ldap` library. It sounds like that method is getting `coid = '08732'` as parameter but it should actually receive `coid_id = '08732'`. Can you put a breakpoint in `C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django_python3_ldap\ldap.py` just **before** line 115, and tell me what's inside the `self._connection.response[0]` object?

Comment: self._connection.response[0] is the users information from AD.  I put the print self._connection.reponse[0] above.  It's a lot of data.

Comment: There isn't enough space to post the data from AD on the print self._connection.reponse[0].    It's the entire AD record, which is over 60k lines.  I'll put a sample of it above so you can get the gist of how bad our AD is.

Comment: Looks like the value of Attribute10 which is the coid is the following:  'extensionAttribute10': [b'08732']   I removed the statement above for security reasons.

Comment: Ah okay I think I got it! In your settings, try changing `"coid": "extensionAttribute10"` to `"coid_id": "extensionAttribute10"`. Hopefully that'll do the trick!

Comment: You are amazing Filly!  I'll mark your solution correct, because you were right from the beginning.

Comment: You're very welcome!!! Glad we found a solution! :D I'll edit the answer to include the actual change that was needed.