# Django - ValueError when trying to update a model object

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django program for a class. I know the error has to do with foreign key assignment but I cannot understand where my flaw in logic is.

Here are the two pertinent models:

```py
    class listing(models.Model):    
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField()
        url = models.URLField(default="", null=True, max_length=100)
        category = models.CharField(default="", max_length=50)
        user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        min_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)


    class watchlist(models.Model):
        item_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
        user_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
        
        #item_id = models.ForeignKey("auctions.listing", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_watchlist")
        #user_id = models.ForeignKey("auctions.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_watchlist")
```

The last two lines in the `watchlist Class` were commented out, allowing the code to work. However, I would like to understand how to make this work as I originally intended. Which is as follows: (the below code fails at the object create a section, with a `ValueError, cannot assign <value>: item_id must be an instance of listings.`)

```py
    @login_required
    def item_listing(request, id):
        itemID = id
    
        # GET call coming in from clicking a title link
        if request.method == "GET":
            item = listing.objects.filter(id=id)
            
            # Check if the item is on the user's watchlist
            if watchlist.objects.filter(item_id=id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():
                watch = True
            else:
                watch = False
    
            return render(request, "auctions/ItemPage.html", {
                "item": item,
                "name": item[0].title,
                "url": item[0].url,
                "description": item[0].description,
                "user_name": item[0].user_name,
                "price": item[0].min_bid,
                "category": item[0].category,
                "watch": watch
            })
    
        # POST call coming in from clicking the watchlist button
        if request.method == "POST":
            
            q = request.POST.get('wl')
            
            # Remove from watchlist. Delete entry in database.
            if q == "Remove from Watchlist":
                watchlist.objects.filter(item_id=id, user_id=request.user.id).delete()
    
            # Add to watchliset. Create entry.
            else:
                watchlist.objects.create (
                    item_id=id, 
                    user_id=request.user.id
                )
    
        # Redirect back to thet page
        pathname = "/" + str(itemID)
        return redirect(pathname)
```

My assumption was that creating the foreign key on the **watchlist** model would limit the choices to the **listing PK**. Deleting an object was no issue, it worked fine. Creating an object with say, Item_id of 7 failed to add to watchlist, even though I could query the listing and indeed the Id of 7 existed:

```py
listing.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<listing: Japanese Tea pot>, <listing: Kindle paperwhite>]>
>>> listing.objects.filter(id=7)
<QuerySet [<listing: Japanese Tea pot>]>
```

So I assume that my understanding of and use of ForiegnKey is flawed. How would I do this correctly?

Also, I apologize if my formatting is off, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913684/valueerror-cannot-assign-must-be-an-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a pretty common mistake. When you create a `ForeignKey` field, it acts as an abstraction from the actual database foreign key relationship. This means that calling a (in your case) `watchlist.item_id` will not return an `id`, but instead the actual `listing` object. This is the same when creating an object.

Create your watchlist with the actual item, instead of the integer value of its id:

```
 watchlist.objects.create (
                    item_id=item, 
                    user_id=request.user.id
                )
```

I'm not sure if passing a key instead of an instance to a model's filter method works, but it's also better to pass the actual object there as well:

```
watchlist.objects.filter(item_id=item, user_id=request.user)
```

This looks a little weird: while you might be used to referring to foreign keys as item_id, it's best to name the foreign key after the actual relationship. So in this case you should change `item_id` in the `watchlist` class to just `item`.

Furthermore, Django classes should be written with a capital letter, so your class should look like this:

```
class Listing(models.Model):    
        ...

class WatchList(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey("auctions.listing", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_watchlist")
    user = models.ForeignKey("auctions.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_watchlist")
```

and then of course your code should be changed to:

```
 WatchList.objects.create (
                    item=item, 
                    user=request.user.id
                )
```

and:

```
WatchList.objects.filter(item=item, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to answer this. I have successfully gotten this to work with your answer.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help :)